# Cut function for continuous columns with condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following generated df :

```
set.seed(100)
df = data.frame(
    Age = sample(18:98, 1000, replace = TRUE),
    Weight = sample(80:250, 1000, replace = TRUE),
    Happy = sample(c('Yes','No','Maybe'), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    College = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)
    
)
```

I want to replace all continuous variables as their respective quantiles only if the column is not binary..

I have the following code but this doesn't account for if a column is binary. How can I do this? I was thinking a case_when statement, but don't know how i can incorporate:

```
df %>% mutate(across(is.numeric, .fn = function(x) cut(x, breaks = 4)))
```

Comment: what is the namespace for the function `where()`? online documentation says its from tidyselect but i get an error ('where' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyselect') when i use `tidyselect::where()`

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(across(tidyselect:::where(~ is.numeric(.) && !all(. %in% c(0, 1),
       na.rm = TRUE)), ~ cut(., breaks = 4)))
```

-output

```
         Age     Weight Happy College
1 (78,98.1]  (208,250] Maybe       1
2 (78,98.1]  (208,250] Maybe       0
3   (38,58]  (165,208] Maybe       0
4 (78,98.1]  (165,208]   Yes       1
5 (17.9,38] (79.8,122] Maybe       0
6   (58,78]  (208,250]   Yes       1
...
```

Comment: A separate function would probably be clearer: `nonbinary <- function (x) ! is.numeric(x) && ! all(x %in% c(0, 1), na.rm = TRUE)`. The `mutate(across(where...)))` approach is also rather verbose, why not something like: `apply(df, 2, \(x) if nonbinary(x) cut(x, 4) else x)`